# Define a one-parameter function that will print friendly numbers

Tags: python

Define a one-parameter function that will print friendly numbers `print_friendly_numbers (n)`, where n is a range in which the friendly numbers will be printed. For n = 10,000, there are five pairs of friend numbers: 220 and 284, 1184 and 1210, 2620 and 2924, 5020 and 5564, and 6232 and 6368. 
**I wrote the beginning of the code, but I don't know how to write a function that prints all friend numbers in the range up to 10,000**

```
def sum_of_divisors(a):
    pom = 1
    for i in range (2, int (sqrt(a)) + 1):
        if a % i == 0:
            pom += i
            if i != a // i:
                pom += a // i
    return pom

def friendly(a, b):
    if(a == sum_of_divisors(b) and sum_of_divisors(a) == b):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

def print_friendly_numbers(n):
```

***DEFINITION OF FRIENDLY NUMBERS 

In number theory, friendly numbers are two or more natural numbers with a common abundancy index, the ratio between the sum of divisors of a number and the number itself. Two numbers with the same "abundancy" form a friendly pair; n numbers with the same "abundancy" form a friendly n-tuple.***

I have function to count sum of divisors. And I have a function to check if the given numbers are friendly.

***How do i need to write this function to output friend numbers in the range up to 10,000?***

Comment: Here is an idea: loop over the numbers and save them in a dict by the abundancy index. Then at the end of the loop you will have a dict with all friendly numbers in the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from itertools in the standard library

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import combinations

def sum_of_divisors(a):
    pom = 1
    for i in range (2, int (sqrt(a)) + 1):
        if a % i == 0:
            pom += i
            if i != a // i:
                pom += a // i
    return pom

def friendly(a, b):
    if a == sum_of_divisors(b) and sum_of_divisors(a) == b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def print_friendly_numbers(n):
    for a, b in combinations(range(n), 2):
        if friendly(a, b):
            print(a, b)

print_friendly_numbers(10000)
```

EDIT:

A much faster method that only requires computing `sum_of_devisors` for each number once:

```
def print_friendly_numbers(n):
    div_sum_map = {}
    for a in range(n):
        div_sum_map[a] = sum_of_divisors(a)
    for a in range(n):
        b = div_sum_map[a]
        if a < b and a == div_sum_map.get(b, None):
            print(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.